# Is this a Russian equivalent of the expression "It’s not in someone's nature to do X"?

Tags: значения, выражения

> **Не дворянское это дело** тратить на поход в магазин или фитнес-клуб массу времени.

```
=??? It’s not in a nobleman's nature to spend much time going to a shop or a fitness club.
```

I assume "дворянское" is the neuter nominative of "дворянский", but does it serve the function of a substantive here with the meaning of "nobleman'**s**" like "**mine**/**yours**", with some word implied: "nobleman's (**nature**/etc)"? That is, instead of an attributive meaning: "nobleman-related" like "my/your"?

I suppose "это дело" serves as the *dummy* subject corresponding to "it" in English, with the *real* subject being "тратить ..."?

Can I interpret the sentence more literally as:

> Not a nobleman's {substantive}, this thing, to spend much time going to a shop or a fitness club.

---

If so, should I use the neuter nominative "моё/mine" to express the idea of "It’s not in **my** nature to do X" or more literally "It’s not **mine**, this thing, to do X"?

> **Не моё это дело** тратить на поход в магазин или фитнес-клуб массу времени.

---

Or does the word order of "Не дворянское это дело" come from "Это не **дворянское**/**моё** дело" {attributive}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Не дворянское это дело* literally means "it's not a nobleman's job", but it's used here as a set phrase meaning "it's beneath you (to spend much time etc.)".

It's more often used as *не царское это дело* ("it's not a royal's job")

In *не моё это дело* the idiomatic meaning is lost, so it just has the literal meaning of "it's not my job".

Comment: I would agree with a lack of an idiomatic meaning. *Не моё это дело* stands for *it's none of my business*.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, that's a modification of a more popular expression:

**Не барское это дело**:

http://dslov.ru/fslov/f373.htm

**Барин** (originally, боярин) - in olden times (like 1.5-2 centuries ago), a higher class man, *master* to his servants, etc. (often addressed so and referred to by them). Also, **барыня** (fem.).

The phrase is often used in the meaning '*it's not worth my (his) time and effort*, [I'd (he'd) rather *hire* somebody for that]'. The modification '*не царское...*' is typically limited in usage to cases where a real boss is involved. The version '*не дворянское.*..' can carry a flavour *'it's below one's self-respect, not worth doing at all*'.

Speaking of the sense '*It's not in someone's nature*...': one can use a more literal expression like **мне это занятие не по душе** or **(мне) не хотелось бы с этим возиться**.

Comment: However, the example of use of "не барское дело" at the link means "this isn't in massa's competence [to seek AND find profit]".

Answer (score 0):

This conversational expression, which is indeed much more popular in the form @Quassnoi points out: "не царское это дело"--"not a job for a tsar", means more precisely "I/you/... won't bother with that" OR even "I/... won't bother [those are sour grapes]".

The expression **might** come from a vulgar joke, where tsar refuses to get intimate with a girl, on the lines: "not a job for a tsar! but if I order it, she'll get intimated all right".

Or both joke and expression might share the same origin, reflected in the expression's form as in the question. I've never encountered a variant with "дворянское дело", but might have heard a variant with "барское дело"--"massa's job".

Answer (score 0):

> “It’s not in someone's nature to do X”

- Не в его́ нату́ре / хара́ктере / обыкнове́нии де́лать X.
- Не в мои́х пра́вилах / привы́чках де́лать X.
- Ему́ несво́йственно де́лать X.

> Not a nobleman's {substantive}, this thing, to spend much time going to a shop or a fitness club.

No, дворя́нское is not substantivised, nor does it imply a noun. It is simply an adjective that agrees with the neuter noun де́ло. "Не дворя́нское э́то де́ло" can be parsed in two ways:

- Э́то (-) не дворя́нское де́ло (This is not a nobleman's affair)
- Э́то де́ло (-) не дворя́нское (This affair is not nobleman's)

(Normally we don't write the dash for a copula before **не**.)

Comment: Thanks for parsing the phrase. This *separated* structure was exactly what I found puzzling. I suppose "Не дворянское" is pushed forward to emphasise the idea of "whose"?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens, exactly.